# JQuery: Turn array input values into a string optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, select

using jQuery I have the following code:

```
var selectedIdsArray = $("#selectId option:selected").map(function(){return this.value;});
var selectedIdsStr = $.map(selectedIdsArray, function(val){ return "" + val + "";});
```

It successfully retrieves a string of ids eg. selectedIdsStr = "2,45,245,1" from an `<select multiple='multiple'>` element. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way (less code) to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could change the second line like this:

```
var selectedIdsStr = selectedIdsArray.get().join(',');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The generated jquery array cannot be joined using the normal js function. At least its not working for me.

Comment: var selectedIdsStr = selectedIdsArray.get().join(',');

I forgot .get() ..sorry

Answer (score 3):

```
var selectedIdsStr = $("#selectId option:selected").map(function(){
   return $(this).val();
}).get().join(",");
```

adapted from http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map#callback

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the second line to this:

```
var selectedIdsStr = selectedIdsArray.get().toString()
```