# How can I send checkboxes data into JSON array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, forms

I'm new to .js and I have a problem with exporting answers from .js checkboxes form into JSON array.

My HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="Question1" id="Answer1" value="Answer1" onclick="show_checked()"/><label for="Answer1">Answer 1</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Question1" id="Answer2" value="Answer2" onclick="show_checked()"/><label for="Answer2">Answer 2</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Question1" id="Answer3" value="Answer3" onclick="show_checked()"/><label for="Answer3">Answer 3</label><br/>
</form>
```

my Javascript:

```
function set_checked(checked) 
    $('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', checked);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[name='Question1']").change(function () {
                var maxAllowed = 2; 
                var cnt = $("input[name='Question1']:checked").length;
                if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
                    $(this).prop("checked", "");
                    alert('Choose max. ' + maxAllowed + ' answers');
                }
            });
        });
```

The question is, how can I send IDs or values of the checked checkboxes into JSON array?

Comment: when you submit the form, the selected item will be sent.

Comment: I'm assuming based on the code that you are using jQuery or is that some other library that uses the "$"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to get values to an array

```
var array =  $("input[name='Question1']:checked").map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get()
```

to get ids to an array

```
var array =  $("input[name='Question1']:checked").map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get()
```

Answer (score 5):

See if this piece of code helps

```
var objArray = [];
$("input[name='Question1']:checked").each(function (index, elem) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
    var obj = {
        Id = id,
        Value = val
    };
    objArray.push(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Comet's answer didn't work for me. This did:

```
var arrCB = {};

$("input[name='Question1']:checked").each(
    function(){
        var id = this.id;
        arrCB[id] = (this.checked ? 1 : 0)
    }
);

var text = JSON.stringify(arrCB);
alert(text);
```

Resources:

http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/associative-arrays-in-javascript/

[best practice for updating a list in database associated with checkboxes in a html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395418/best-practice-for-updating-a-list-in-database-associated-with-checkboxes-in-a-ht/25437847#25437847)

[How can I send checkboxes data into JSON array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182189/how-can-i-send-checkboxes-data-into-json-array)

[JQuery: Turn array input values into a string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172144/jquery-turn-array-input-values-into-a-string-optimization)