# Turn selection of elements/values into assoc array / json string

Tags: jquery, json

I need to save/retrieve a series of checkboxes/values from webpage to PHP to MySQL, and back again.

In MySQL, they will be stored as a JSON string, like this: `{"cb1":0,"cb2":0,"cb3":1,"cb4":0}`

Everything is working except (1) reading the checkboxes+vals into an array, and (2) converting it back into JSON string as shown above.

It is the `Display JSON List (#display_all)` button that needs rescuing.

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k20mug9y/)

**Example HTML:**

```
<div id="chkbox"></div>
<input type="button" id="create_cb" value="Create Checkboxes" />
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Add New Checkbox" />
<input type="button" id="display_all" value="Display JSON list" />
```

**Example JS:**

```
var chk, json = '{"cb1":0,"cb2":0,"cb3":1,"cb4":0}';

$('#create_cb').click(function(){
    var arrJson = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
    for(key in arrJson){
        chk = (arrJson[key]==1)? 'checked="checked"' : '';
        $('#chkbox').append(key +': <input id="'+key+'" type="checkbox" '+chk+' /> ');
    }
    $(this).hide();
    $('#display_all').show();
});

$('#display_all').click(function(){
    var arrCB = $("#chkbox>input[type='checkbox']").map(function(){return this.value;});
    var text = JSON.stringify(arrCB);
    alert(text);
});
```

I have reviewed the following SO posts but cannot work out how to use these solutions in my case.

[How can I send checkboxes data into JSON array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182189/how-can-i-send-checkboxes-data-into-json-array)

[JQuery: Turn array input values into a string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172144/jquery-turn-array-input-values-into-a-string-optimization)

### Edit

I understand from [this](http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/associative-arrays-in-javascript/) and [this](http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/) that the term "associative array" is incorrect. I am really creating an object with multiple properties. However, the term used best conveys the desired stringified result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your arrCB as an anonymous object, then loop over your checkboxes and assign their IDs in to arrCB:

```
$('#display_all').click(function(){
    var arrCB = {};
    $("#chkbox>input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){ 
        var el = $(this);
        var id = el.attr('id');
        arrCB[id] = (this.checked ? 1 : 0)
    });
    var text = JSON.stringify(arrCB);
    alert(text);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k20mug9y/2/